# Раздел страниц HTML по категориям

Tags: html

Моя проблема в том что я хочу разделить страницы HTML по разделам, категориям.(В силу своего незнания возможно ошибочно выражаю свои мысли) К примеру у меня есть 4 страниц. index.html , products.html , product-1.html , product-2.html. Я бы хотел что бы страницы products-1 , products-2.html имели адрес : www.domen/products/product-1.html/ . Как мне это реализовать ?
- Спасибо!

Comment: сложить их в папку `products`?

Comment: @teran нет, products.html - страница с описанием товаром. а products-1.html, products-2.html отдельные страницы о товаре... Мне бы хотелось при открывании этих страниц был адрес https://www.domen.ru/products/products-1.html . Это вроде называется Подстраницами?

Comment: @teran то есть лучше создать папку products? А это решение является оптимальным?

Comment: если у вас речь идет про статичные html страницы безо всякого программирования а-ля пхп или c# и т.п., то решение вроде логичное.

Comment: понятно, спасибо.